# How to add auto-increment ID?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am attempting to add an AutoIncrement ID to my database table, and also display it when the user selects, "View All".
However, after adding to my table the application will crash, I believe that I am doing one of these processes incorrectly.
The following code is my current implementation without my attempt at using AUTOINCREMENT.
If anyone can assist in this initialization I would greatly appreciate it; thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText fname,lname,cost,make,model;
Button add,view,viewall,Show1,delete,modify;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    lname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    cost=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cost);
    make=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.make);
    model=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.model);
    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
    viewall=(Button)findViewById(R.id.viewallbtn);
    delete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.deletebtn);
    Show1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.showbtn);
    modify=(Button)findViewById(R.id.modifybtn);

    db=openOrCreateDatabase("CARDEALER", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,cost INTEGER,make VARCHAR, model VARCHAR, fname VARCHAR, lname VARCHAR);");


    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(cost.getText().toString().trim().length()==0||
                    make.getText().toString().trim().length()==0||
                    model.getText().toString().trim().length()==0||
                    fname.getText().toString().trim().length()==0||
                    lname.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
            {
                showMessage("Error", "Please enter all values");
                return;
            }
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('"+id.getText()+"','"+cost.getText()+"','"+make.getText()+"','"+model.getText()+"','"+fname.getText()+
                    "','"+lname.getText()+"');");
            showMessage("Success", "Record added successfully");
            clearText();
        }
    });
    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(cost.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
            {
                showMessage("Error", "Please enter Cost");
                return;
            }
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE cost='"+cost.getText()+"'", null);
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM student WHERE cost='"+cost.getText()+"'");
                showMessage("Success", "Record Deleted");
            }
            else
            {
                showMessage("Error", "Invalid Cost");
            }
            clearText();
        }
    });
    modify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(cost.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
            {
                showMessage("Error", "Please enter Cost");
                return;
            }
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE cost='"+cost.getText()+"'", null);
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                db.execSQL("UPDATE student SET make='"+make.getText()+"',model='"+model.getText()+"',fname='"+fname.getText()+"',lname='"+lname.getText()+
                        "' WHERE cost='"+cost.getText()+"'");
                showMessage("Success", "Record Modified");
            }
            else
            {
                showMessage("Error", "Invalid Cost");
            }
            clearText();
        }
    });

    viewall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);
            if(c.getCount()==0)
            {
                showMessage("Error", "No records found");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
            while(c.moveToNext())
            {
                buffer.append("ID: "+c.getString(0)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Cost: "+c.getString(1)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Make: "+c.getString(2)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Model: "+c.getString(3)+"\n");
                buffer.append("First Name: "+c.getString(4)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Last Name: "+c.getString(5)+"\n\n");
            }
            showMessage("Customer Detail", buffer.toString());
        }
    });
    Show1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showMessage("Customer Management Application", "Developed By Tanner Tattini");
        }
    });

}
public void showMessage(String title,String message)
{
    Builder builder=new Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
public void clearText()
{
    cost.setText("");
    make.setText("");
    model.setText("");
    fname.setText("");
    lname.setText("");
    cost.requestFocus();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.customer_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Error is on line 56:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('"+cost.getText()+"','"+make.getText()+"','"+model.getText()+"','"+fname.getText()+
                    "','"+lname.getText()+"');");
```

Comment: Show the crash details from the log or the debugger. Also, a reminder that you are using unsanitized input directly in SQL statements, so you now have to [worry about mom](https://www.xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Could I simply create the table as,("ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, cost INTEGER,make VARCHAR, model VARCHAR, fname VARCHAR, lname VARCHAR);");

And then display the value later when the user selects "View All"

Comment: And yes I am aware, this is just for a school project

Comment: You should show what you have tried in the question itself. As it stands, this is a small program you have written that isn't working right. Time to learn the greatest skill you will ever learn as a coder: debugging. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ (Your last comment is very ironic, given the context of the XKCD panel I linked.)

Comment: Oh the irony..School references

Comment: I have updated my original post with my implementation attempt and error location. Again the application runs find without the AUTOINCREMENT tag

Comment: You don't show the crash details. For instance, this might be a `PurpleMonkeyFlewOutOfMyServerException` or something else. Work from the known to the unknown, starting with the error. Form a hypothesis. Test the hypothesis. Repeat. (I have to level with you: you aren't going to get much traction on this question, as folks here will expect you to do your own debugging. If you need specific help understanding an aspect of that, feel free to ask.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add null;

remove the single quotation marks from the cost;

Make it

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES(null,"+cost.getText()+",'"+make.getText()+"','"+model.getText()+"','"+fname.getText()+
                "','"+lname.getText()+"');");
```

Comment: This was the fix I was missing! Thank you